# How to fully print outer loop before inner loop (Java)

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

My goal is to print a chart that displays "enemy" number, x and y coordinates, then their distance in respect to the other "enemies", but with my following nested loop below, the enemy number, and coordinates are reversed with the distance numbers. I've tried adjusting the position of the codes, but they don't seem to fix the issue.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    // array of enemy coordinates
    int[] xCoords = {1, 4, 5, 5, 7, 10};
    int[] yCoords = {3, 4, 6, 2, 5, 2};
    
    
    System.out.println("________Enemy Distance Chart________");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t\tDistance To (Kilometers)");
    System.out.println("Enemies\t  X Coord  \tY Coord  \tE-0\tE-1\tE-2\tE-3\tE-4\tE-5");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            double distance = Math.sqrt((yCoords[j]-yCoords[i])*(yCoords[j]-yCoords[i]) + (xCoords[j]-xCoords[i])*(xCoords[j]-xCoords[i]));
            System.out.printf("%.2f\t", distance);  
        }
        // the following code below is somehow printed on the far right 
        System.out.println("E- " + i + "\t\t  " + xCoords[i] + "\t      " + yCoords[i]); 
    }
```

Comment: Print the ID and coordinates first, at the top of the outer loop and before the inner loop starts.

Comment: @codebod I've tried that, and the ID & coordinates only get printed once, without printing the distances on the same line. After that, everything that is printed remains the same as before doing that adjustment. That's where I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        System.out.printf("E-" + i + "\t\t" + xCoords[i] + "\t\t" + yCoords[i] + "\t\t");
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            double distance = Math.sqrt((yCoords[j] - yCoords[i]) * (yCoords[j] - yCoords[i]) + (xCoords[j] - xCoords[i]) * (xCoords[j] - xCoords[i]));
            System.out.printf("%.2f\t", distance);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much, this worked.